# Prolog predicate doesn't resolve

Tags: list, prolog, prolog-findall

This may be a rookie mistake, but I'm trying to solve this question:

Find the query to obtain the following answer using the findall predicate: Obtain a list of persons who work in a city other than the one where they live:

```
L = [suzy, paul].
```

This is the database:

```
city(ottawa,ontario).
city(toronto,ontario).
city(kingston,ontario).
city(gatineau,quebec).
city(montreal,quebec).

company(shopify,ottawa).
company(rossvideo,ottawa).
company(dium,gatineau).
company(uber,toronto).
company(deepmind,montreal).
company(google,toronto).

person(annie,gatineau).
person(paul,gatineau).
person(suzy,gatineau).
person(robert,gatineau).
person(tom,ottawa).
person(tim,kingston).
person(joe,montreal).
person(jane,ottawa).
person(marie,ottawa).
person(jack,toronto).
person(simon,toronto).

employee(annie,dium).
employee(tom,shopify).
employee(jane,shopify).
employee(marie,shopify).
employee(joe,deepmind).
employee(jack,google).
employee(simon,google).
employee(suzy,shopify).
employee(paul,rossvideo).
employee(marie,rossvideo).
employee(simon,uber).
```

Here is the predicate I tried to use to solve it:

```
worksIn(n, Y) :-
   employee(n, Comp),
   company(Comp, Y).
```

But it only returns `false`. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I think you are supposed to use `findall/3`.

Comment: `n` is not in your DataBase so it will return false btw use capital letter for `n`.  `worksIn(N, Y) :- employee(N,Comp), company(Comp, Y).` it's not recursive , so you can simply write `employee(N,Comp), company(Comp, Y).`

Comment: `n` is not a variable in Prolog. It's an atom. Variables that you care about need to start with a capital letter. Or if you don't care about the value, then starts with `_`.

Answer (score 0):

I did:

```
worksIn(P):- person(P,CL), employee(P, CO), company(CO, CW), CL/=CW.
```

so the final answer is:

```
findall(P, worksIn(P), L).
```

I'm not sure if we can add the "worksIn" thing in or not

Answer (score -1):

when use variables, first letter must be uppercase.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18901955)

Comment: I disagree. "worksIn(n, Y) " part is critically make questioner code fail and correctting n to upper case letter is definitely required.

Comment: @TakuKoyahata True, but it isn't a complete answer to the question asked and would have been better as a comment. There's nothing wrong with the content of what you're saying, but where it's placed.